# How do I extract the values for z-scores for a specified normal distribution?

Tags: r

My q is two-fold:

1) How do I create a basic normal distribution with `mean = 100` and `sd = 5`

2) How would I extract the values from the distribution which correspond to the following z-scores?

`z_scores <- seq(-3, 3, length = 50)`

Comment: Reading the documentation to `rnorm` by entering `?rnorm` into the RStudio console should help considerably here.

Comment: For question one, what exactly is the output you want when you "create a distribution"? A distribution isn't really an object or anything in base R. And what "values from the distribution" are you talking about exactly. Are you talking about the value of the probability density function? Are you talking about the probability of observing a value at least as large as each of those z-scores?

Comment: @MrFlick Using [this](https://analytics.seandolinar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/Normal_Z_Comparison.png) graph as an example, the values would be the height measurement corresponding at each z-score in my `z_scores` vector.

Comment: Late to the game, but it looks like you actually need a probability density function. https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78711/how-to-find-estimate-probability-density-function-from-density-function-in-r

Answer (score 0):

Normal distribution can be achieved using [`pnorm` function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html).

To get a z-score from mean and standard deviation use this equation:

[image]

Where x is your data point, mu is the mean, and sigma is standard deviation. And in R:

```
zscore <- (x - mean) / stdev
```

You can than use that to build z-scores for any point you want.